# When using Spring, When is the Form class property stored in the value that's sent from the html form tag?

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I should implement like `execute(@ModelAttribute RegisterForm registerForm, Model model)` in Controller class below.
I forgot put the `@ModelAttribute`.
However it works. When is `name` in RegisterForm class stored in the value that's sent from html?

Part of Controller class

```
@Controller
public class RegisterController {

  @RequestMapping(value = "/register/")
  public String register() {
      return "register";
  }

  @RequestMapping(value="/register/execute", method=RequestMethod.POST)
  //(@ModelAttribute RegisterForm registerForm, Model model) is better
  public String execute(RegisterForm registerForm, Model model) {
      model.addAttribute("registered_name", registerForm.getName());
      return "index";
  }
}
```

Form class

```
public class RegisterForm {

  private String name; //when is this property stored in the value??

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }
}
```

Part of HTML file

```
<div class="input">
    <p>Enter your name</p>
    <input type="text" name="name" />
</div>
```

Please let me know if you need more information to solve this.Thanks.

Comment: Update your question with all code from your controller. We cannot figure it from a single method.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.I updated my question.

Comment: @tekun its working because you have in your form the object="registerForm" then Spring is going to try to map all your attributes inside your object class searching for getters/setters. If you change the form attribute name, wont work

Comment: Thank you for your answer.Do not I have to implement `@ModelAttribute` annotation??

Answer (score -1):

add setter name to your class RegisterForm  it's important

you should lik this  :

```
<form action="register/execute">
<div class="input">
    <p>Enter your name</p>
    <input type="text" name="name" />
</div>
<form>
```

or usign tag form spring  :

add this in  your controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/index", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String executet(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("registerForm ", new RegisterForm ());
    return "index";
}
```

include this code in your jsp

```
   <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>

<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="registerForm ">
  <form:input path="name" />
 <input type="submit" value="Register">
</form:form>
```

Comment: Sorry, the html file is just "part of html file".
I already implement those tags.
And It already works. I want to know why it works.When the name property is stored the value that is sent from html form tag.